# How to catch a table in POST and use it as an array

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

so basically to lay this out I have

- AffidavitController - Controller
- Affidavit.jsp - GET view page
- summary.jsp - POST view page

so basically I have a form that a user fills out and then they hit the submit button and it posts it.

This method is then called in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/affidavit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(AffidavitDetailDto affidavitDetail, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
```

now within this method I catch the information that was passed over in the response object.

an example of this is I have a name field on the GET view page and the name of this field is  'custName'

so I catch it like so

```
    String contactName = request.getParameter("custName");
    model.addAttribute("contactName", contactName);
```

and then I can display it on my POST view page

```
                 <p>Name:  ${contactName}</p>
```

but now I am trying to figure out how I can do the same with a table and treat it like an array

the following is how it is added on the GET view page

```
<table id="certEmail" name="certEmail">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${user.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

the following is what I have attempted

```
    String[] certEmail = request.getParameterValues("certEmail");

    model.addAttribute("certEmail", certEmail);
```

and this is what I have on the view page to display it

```
            <div id="Emails">

                <c:forEach items="${certEmail}" var="email">

                    <p>${email}</p>

                </c:forEach>

            </div>
```

this does not currently work.  I know I am probably just doing it wrong so can someone please at least point me in right direction. I just haven't figured out a good google query yet to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table is not a form element (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp). Only form element values on form are submitted to server. So instead of

```
<table id="certEmail" name="certEmail">
    <tr>
        <td>${user.email}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You should have something like

```
<table id="certEmail">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="certEmail" value="${user.email}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you want your data to be editable, or

```
<table id="certEmail">
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${user.email}
            <input type="hidden" name="certEmail" value="${user.email}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you want it to be hidden and just resent to the server.

While I should denote that second variant generally should be avoided. I would recommend you to pass the **user id** and use it in back-end to load user and read his email.

Please learn how to use HTML forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel pretty silly I missed that.